# How can i remove from a treeView1 only the selected child node?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I have this event where i select with the mouse a node in the `treeView1`:

```
private void treeView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);

        if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null)
        {
            menuStrip.Show(treeView1, e.Location);
        }
    }
}
```

Then i have context menu strip i select fro example delete to remove directory:
After the directory removed i want to update the treeView1 structure visualy in the place was remove i mean the node/child node i selected.

```
private void RemoveDirectory(string remoteFile, bool fileordir)
{
    remoteFile = remoteFile.Replace('\\', '/');
    if (remoteFile.StartsWith("root"))
    {
        remoteFile = remoteFile.Replace("root", string.Empty);
    }
    string deleteRequest = txtHost.Text + remoteFile;
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + deleteRequest);
    if (fileordir == true)
    {
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.RemoveDirectory;
    }
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
    request.Proxy = null;
    request.UseBinary = false;
    request.UsePassive = true;
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    sr.ReadToEnd();
    string StatusCode = response.StatusDescription;
    sr.Close();
    response.Close();
    treeView1.SelectedNode.Remove();
}
```

In the bottom i added the line:

```
treeView1.SelectedNode.Remove();
```

But this will remove the whole node.
For example if i selected child node /b/c/d/e/f if i selected to remove e then only e and f should be removed.

If i select to remove b then b c d e f should remove.

I didn't find any selected property for the specific child node.

This is a screenshot of what i mean:

[image: Remove Child Selected Node]

In this case i clicked on selected the child node $Recycle Bin
When i click on delete i want to remove from the treeView1 the $Recycle Bin and the files inside $Recycle Bin  but i wan that C will stay will not be removed.

So on root i will see C but inside C there will be nothing since i removed only $Recycle Bin
And if i was clicking on C and make delete then i want to make treeView1.SelectedNode.Remove(); that will remove/delete the whole C node.

The question is how can i remove only child node and the files inside from the treeView1 i mean that i will not see them it dosen't mean i remove them from hard disk or my ftp server i just don't want to see the $recycle Bin and the files inside in the treeView1.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the whole node"? Please explain (or attach a picture) that shows the expected result.

Comment: Either use the OnClick event of the node, set it as selected and then remove that node, or iterate through all the nodes till it lands on the node in question, and remove it that way. As for removing the directory and having the node reflect the changes. You can delete the node and then rebuild it based off the method you used to build the treeview in the first place.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense.  If you let the FTP server delete a directory then all the files and subdirectories should get deleted as well.  And then of course it makes sense that the sub-nodes in the tree are removed as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to reference the parent node, which either belongs to the TreeView control, or the parent node of the SelectedNode:

```
if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null) {
  if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent == null) {
    treeView1.Nodes.Remove(treeView1.SelectedNode);
  } else {
    treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Nodes.Remove(treeView1.SelectedNode);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method searching a node in your tree from a rootnode.

```
private TreeNode GetNodeByStringPath(TreeNode root, string path)
    {
        string[] pathArr = path.Split('/');
        if (pathArr.First() != root.Name)
            return null;
        TreeNode currentNode = root;
        for (int i = 1; i < pathArr.Length &&currentNode!=null; i++)
        {
            int index = currentNode.Nodes.IndexOfKey(pathArr[i]);
            currentNode = currentNode.Nodes[index];
        }
        return currentNode;
    }
```

You can use it like this:

```
        string path = "a/b/c/d/e";
        TreeNode node = GetNodeByStringPath(treeView1.Nodes[0], path);
```